# Referencing table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have a big problem with referencing my tables. Below is how I do it. The pdf seems to know which table I refer to (the reference links me to the right table), but instead of a number it writes "??".

Table \ref{medaltable} summarizes the results

```
\begin{table}
\label{medaltable}
\caption{The summary of the performance of the algorithms in terms of the number of    nodes activated during the information diffusion}
\center
\begin{tabular}{ | l | c | c | c | c | }
\toprule
\textit{algorithm} & \textit{first} & \textit{second} & \textit{third} & \textit{total}     \\ \hline
GR & 4 & 4 & 2 & 22  \\
SHALG & 4  & 3 & 4 & 22  \\ 
CUST2 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 21 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: have you compiled your source file more than once?  latex puts the value for the `\label` into the `.aux` file in the first pass, and reads it back in (and outputs it) in the second pass.  also, `\label` must be input *after* `\caption`, since it picks up the value of the last referenceable object, and that (for a table or figure) is the `\caption`.  so in this example, the cross-reference won't be the table, but whatever might have been numbered previously, like a `\section`.

Comment: This is a very often asked question: the `\label` command must go after the `\caption`. Don't use `\center`, but rather `\centering`. And don't add vertical rules in tables, if you're going to use `\toprule` and friends; better yet, never use vertical rules in tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `\label` *after* the `\caption` because `\label` actually references the last modified counter and `\caption` steps the counter. So if you issue `\label` before `\caption` the counter that was modified *before* the table is referenced.

I have also taken the liberty of modifying your table a little bit using `booktabs`: it is recommended not to use vertical lines, I have also replaced `\hline` by `\midrule` (compare the spacing around the rule), finally I used `\emph` instead of `\textit` (but that is really a matter of taste: I assumed you wanted to emphasise the heads).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ l c c c c }
      \toprule
      \emph{algorithm} & \emph{first} & \emph{second} & \emph{third} & \emph{total}\\
      \midrule
      GR & 4 & 4 & 2 & 22\\
      SHALG & 4  & 3 & 4 & 22\\ 
      CUST2 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 21\\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The summary of the performance of the algorithms in terms of the number of nodes activated during the information diffusion}
    \label{tab:medaltable}
  \end{table}
  Lets \verb|\ref| the table: \ref{tab:medaltable}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the reference to jump to the beginning of the table, not the caption itself, add `\usepackage[all]{hyperref}` to the preamble (be aware that `hypcap` might conflict with packages redefining `\caption` macro).